# tensorflow installation

Tags: nvidia

I am trying to install tensorflow in my ubuntu 14.04 and I am following installation guide https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup.html#configure-the-installation

After downloading the TF source, I just ran ./configure and I am being asked if TensorFlow to  build with OpenCL support? - I see no such option listed in the above link. And I am seeing new options when I configure in my ubuntu PC.

I am new to GPU and TF coding. Should it run with OpenCL support?

Answer (score 0):

[OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) is a framework for writing programs that will allow its execution on CPU's (Central Processing Unit) and GPGPU's (General Purpose Graphics Processing Unit).  When executed on the GPGPU, the computer can offload the work to the Graphics card, freeing up the CPU for other work.

This is especially handy in single streams of data that require repetitive calculations, such as Video Encoding/Decoding; Cryptography; Computation such as R etc.

The short version is:

- Most GPU's in recent years support OpenCL
- Tensorflow is a computation library, so OpenCL support could speed up the process if you have a supported graphics card, and configure it properly
- You do not NEED a graphics card to run OpenCL applications, as they will run on a CPU (albeit much slower)

There is some debate these days over the validity of using OpenCL/[CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) for these kinds of things, as it's almost as easy to manufacture a dedicated chip ([NVENC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_NVENC) for example, sometimes called an [ASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-specific_integrated_circuit)).

Speed increases using OpenCL can range from excellent, to below expectations.  If you have a spare card that supports OpenCL laying around, then it's well worth trying.  It can (in some circumstances) increase computational speed quite dramatically.

When it doesnt work though, it can be a nightmare of configuration and setup for minimal gain.